# Pipe output to file using OSX authopen programmatically

Tags: c, pipe, exec, fork, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to elevate my program's privileges, to write a file to a system location. I am doing this in C on OSX, by forking a child process that uses `authopen` to create and write to a file.

I can create the file, however I'm having difficulty writing a string to it. From the man pages of `authopen`, I can use `-w` to direct `stdin` to the file if `-stdoutpipe` is not declared. I don't want to read from `stdin`, but I want to write a constant str to the file.

I find the description of `-stdoutpipe` confusing on the man pages, and there are no examples online on how to use this flag. Can anyone offer any advice how to accomplish this?

My code:

```
pid_t processId = fork();
if (processId == 0) {
    //in child process
    const char * authopenPath = "/usr/libexec/authopen";

    //Create the file fromProg if it does not exist. This works OK.
    execl(authopenPath,
          authopenPath,
          "-c",
          "/etc/fromProg",
          NULL);

    //This is where I need help.
    execl(authopenPath,
            authopenPath,
            "-stdoutpipe",    //<- Not sure how to write a string to file using this
            //-w -a",         //<- Or this
            "/etc/fromProg",
            NULL);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got this to work so I'll answer my own question for others.

In a nutshell, the string should be sent by the parent process through a pipe, and the dup function conveniently duplicates the read end of the pipe to stdin.

Also, I found this reference on [creating pipes](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) very helpful.

```
    int pip[2];

    if (pipe(pip) != 0){
        //error creating pipe
        exit(1);
    }

    pid_t processId;
    processId = fork();

    if (processId == -1) {
        //error creating fork
        exit(1);
    }

    if (processId == 0) {
        //in child process

        //close write end of pipe
        close(pip[1]);

        //close stdin and duplicate the read end of pipe to stdin
        close(0);
        dup(pip[0]);

        //test reading from stdin
        //char buffer[35];
        //read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 35);
        //printf("Received string: %s", buffer);

        const char * authopenPath = "/usr/libexec/authopen";

        execl(authopenPath,
              authopenPath,
              "-c","-w","-a",
              "/etc/fromProg",
              NULL);

        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        //in parent process

        //close read end of pipe
        close(pip[0]);

        //write to write end of pipe
        char string[] = "Helloooo Pipe!\n";
        write(pip[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
    }
```

Comment: Also note that dup2 can replace the 2 calls to close and dup.